# Finite limits in derived categories

Tags: derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be an abelian category with finite limits, let $D(\mathcal{A})$ be its derived category.

(1)Does $K(\mathcal{A})$ admit finite limits?

(2)Does $D(\mathcal{A})$ admit finite limits?

(3) I think there are two notion of exactness for a functor $F\colon D(\mathcal{A})\to D(\mathcal{B})$, one of them is: it sends distinguished triangles to distinguished triangles. Another is the $F$ preserve finite limits(left exact) and colimits(right exact). I am just wondering if this two definitions are the same, or even if the question make sense.

Comment: Taking finite limits is not exact (in $A$), so is itself an operation that needs to be derived in the setting of derived categories: you need to consider what are called homotopy limits.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks for the comment, Apart from this I heard that derived category is not the correct setting to discuss construction of limits, etc, while $\infty$-category are the natural setting where the construction work better, do you know some concrete statements I can read about? Or how can we upgrade derived category to $\infty$-category? Thanks a lot!